# Sumproduct Status Bar VBA

Tags: excel, vba, statusbar

newbie here,

I am trying to make a VBA code to display SumProduct in the status bar

Here is my code for the inserted Module:

```
Option Explicit
Public SrPr As Long
Public rng As Range

Sub SumProduct()

SrPr = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumProduct(rng)
Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
Application.StatusBar = "SumProduct: " & SrPr

End Sub
```

After this i selected a Sheet in Excel objects and inserted the following:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Set rng = Target
Call SumProduct

End Sub
```

I then proceeded to test my code,but the calculation is wrong and i get the following error after clicking away:

**Runtime error 1004: Unable to get the Sumproduct property of the WorksheetFunction class**

Comment: Sumproduct is also mean to handle more than one array generally. What are you actually trying to do with rng? And you should call a sub after a function i.e. do not call it sumproduct.

Comment: I am trying to click and drag selection to display the Sumproduct in the Status Bar  
exactly  like the Sum/Average/Count  in the status bar when you click and drag selection in sheet

Comment: I am not sure where your status bar is... mine is usually below and you appear to have write syntax for updating. You error is as per my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

For your error:

`SUMPRODUCT` does not work in VBA. You would use `EVALUATE` with the string function inside to perform a calculation with it.

So this, `SrPr = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumProduct(rng)`, is not valid.

However,

Pseudo: `SrPr = Evaluate("=SumProduct(...)")`

is valid.

Note:

`SUMPRODUCT` is also mean to handle more than one array generally.

If you wish to sum `rng` then do

```
Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(rng)
```

And you should not name a sub after a function i.e. do not call it sumproduct. E.g. call it `SumRange`

Answer (score 0):

1. Sounds like you don't need to use Sumproduct here, a simple `SUM` will do. Not to mention, Sumproduct is not even a vba method, which will result in error.
2. You are selecting your range incorrectly. Or well, to phrase myself better, your code does work, but the selection itself doesn't make sense, itwill always be only the most recently changed cell instead of all the cells. Seems to make little sense from logical point of view to sum a single cell.
   I would just recommend changing to a dynamic range
3. **Don't use public to declare temporary procedure variables. Use `Dim` instead!** (unless you have some specific reason behind making them public for your scope)

> In the example I provided I just summed all the active (with value) cells in worksheet, but feel free to change the range to whatever you want

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub sum_active_cells()
  Dim lr as Long, lc as Long
  Dim rng as Range
  lr = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
  lc = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Row
  Set rng = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(lr, lc))

  Dim result as Long
  result = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(rng)
  Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
  Application.StatusBar = "Sumproduct: " & result

End Sub
```